# Parsing MIME body parts in Python

Tags: python, email, imap, mime

I'm having trouble parsing specific body parts of MIME messages.

I have an email client web interface. I want to allow the user to download the attachments of an email. In the past, each time I wanted to download an attachment I would make a call to the IMAP server with the argument RFC822 to obtain the whole message, that I could easily parse with Python.

However, this is not efficient and I need a way to obtain just the required attachment. I'm using the alternative of making a call to the IMAP server with the BODY[1], BODY[2], etc index of the specific bodypart.

When I make this IMAP call I obtain back the correct body part (when I make a call to BODYSTRUCTURE, the number of bytes in the part I'm looking for adds up, so I'm definitely obtaining the correct part).

However, I cannot parse this body part into something useable, or save it for that matter.

A specific example: I make a call to obtain the BODY[1] of an email and obtain back

```
 ('4 (UID 26776 BODY[2] {5318}', '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAoHBwkHBgoJCAkLCwoMDxkQDw4ODx4WFxIZJCAmJSMg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\r\nCiiigD//2Q==\r\n').
```

This specific response corresponds to a JPEG image attachment.

I tried extracting the string representing the body part (so, I'm talking about the string starting in '/9j' and ending in '2Q==\r\n') and saving that to a file as a .jpg, but it's not a valid file.

I then though that, as there are multiple instances of \r\n in that string, that the string might be split with newline/carriage return, so I split the string and stripped it of the \r\n, then joined the substrings and tried to save that to a file. Still not a valid JPEG file.

What can I do to try and parse this response?

Thank you.

Comment: What does the `BODYSTRUCTURE` command return for that part?

Comment: I will omit the full BODYSTRUCTURE response, but the part of it relating to this part, after parsing, is: ['IMAGE', 'JPEG', ['NAME', 'image001.jpg'], '<image001.jpg@01CDE914.6E62F850>', None, 'BASE64', 5318, None, None, None]

Comment: I just realized that the reference to BASE64 in the response might indicate the BODY[2] response might actually be BASE64 encoded. Would this make sense?

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking... thank you. Will try and update question soon.

Comment: Martjin, tried it and it works. You can re-type your comment as a reply so I can mark it as correct if you want the credit. Thank you !

Comment: I already expanded it into an answer, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the `BODYRESPONSE` string to see what format the data is encoded in, see the [IMAP RFC 3501, section 7.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-7.4.2). The 5th field is the content encoding:

```
['IMAGE', 'JPEG', ['NAME', 'image001.jpg'], '<image001.jpg@01CDE914.6E62F850>', None, 'BASE64', 5318, None, None, None]
```

The fields are, in order, the type and subtype (so `image/jpeg` in this case), body parameters (such as characterset, format-flowed, or the filename in this case), the attachment id, description, encoding, size, MD5 signature (if any), disposition and language.

In this case the data is base-64 encoded:

```
>>> imagedata = datastring.decode('base64')
>>> imagedata[:10]
'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF'
```

which looks like JPEG data to me.